# Is it haram for girls to post their pics on the internet without hijab?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab, image

Occasionally, it is seen that some Muslim girls/women post their images on different internet websites **without veil (hijab)**. Based on Islam, it is Haram (forbidden) for women to expose their bodies and their beauties for strangers as non-mahram(s); and factually only Mahrams can see their hairs. Accordingly, would it be haram to do it in some parts of virtual world such as Internet, which is full of non-mahrams there?

Comment: Read other questions tagged as Hijab before just asking another question regarding Hijab

Comment: If something is haram its haram everywhere. Here is an answer I posted about my opinion on Hijab @ http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25111/12537

Comment: I think hijab should be mandatory for men too. Men should not reveal themselves to random women on internet. As always , Allah  knows the best.

Answer (score 5):

Assalamu-alaikum,

I think we first need to understand the meaning of hijab ourselves. Without that this question and its answers bears no value.

> Merely covering dress is not the idea, but more importantly, it is behavior, manners, speech and appearance in public. The idea for men and women is an outer manifestation of an inner commitment to worshipping Allah , it symbolizes a commitment to piety. Self or inner morality is what gives meaning to the modest clothing. -- http://www.whyislam.org/social-values-in-islam/gender-relations-in-islam/hijab/

Secondly, should the pictures of men or women in complete hijab be posted?
Even with hijab there is a lot of corruption that could happen. So it's best to avoid it altogether.

*And Allah knows best.*

Comment: uh, yeah. you mentioned a significant point. Actually, at the initial step we ought to figure out regarding the precise meaning of hijab. Good luck mate for indicating such an important point.

Comment: your last point as you mentioned can be discussed a lot as well, as you said "Even with hijab there is a lot of corruption that could happen" . In truth, what you said is absolutely trueeee. Since even Satan perhaps deceive the .. in that case. Therefore the best aspect can be avoiding pasting it at all. جزاکم الله خیرا

Answer (score 2):

According to the view of Shi'a:

Definitely, it is haram (prohibited) for girls to put their photos on the internet without hijab (veil).So when Allah has said it is Haram for females if any man (except Mahrams) see their hairs,
as a result we understand that it is absolutely Haram..

Well, Haram is Haram, there is not any difference between "internet or other places".
Thus I strongly ask ladies don't put their photos (without hijab) on the internet.
God bless you.

Comment: but most people use "hijab" not for veil, but for a type of cloth, that may be also without veil

Answer (score 2):

Man or woman, you shouldn't post your pictures online where they are always available to see for anyone who chooses to at will. This applies to profile pictures in apps like facebook, twitter, whatsapp too. Remember purdah is equally important for a man too. Islam doesn't differentiate between sexes when it comes to modesty.

> *The Glorious Quraan: Surah An-Nur: 30-31*
>
> *"Tell the believing men to lower their gaze and be modest. That is
> purer for them. Lo! Allah is Aware of what they do. And tell the
> believing women to lower their gaze and be modest."*

Prophet Muhammad confirmed on this as seen in this Hadith -

> *Sahih Al-Bukhari Hadith 8.260 Narrated by Ibn Abbas:*
>
> *I have not seen a thing resembling 'lamam' (minor sins) than what Abu Huraira narrated from the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him)who
> said "Allah has written for the children of Adam their share of ‘zina’
> which he commits inevitably. **The ‘zina’ of the eyes is the sight (to
> gaze at a forbidden thing)**, the ‘zina’ of the tongue is the talk,
> and the inner self wishes and desires and the private parts testify
> all this or deny it.*

Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it haram to put photos without hijab, it is also haram or makrooh to make photos with hijab, due to the ruling on making imagery. Some scholars have ruled photographs as separate from the prohibition of making images, suggesting it is a capture of images instead. Regardless, even they have said it is better to not take photographs, so as to stay away from doubtful matters, as the Prophet said:

> عَنِ النُّعْمَانِ بْنِ بَشِيرٍ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ الْحَلاَلُ بَيِّنٌ، وَالْحَرَامُ بَيِّنٌ
>   وَبَيْنَهُمَا أُمُورٌ مُشْتَبِهَةٌ، فَمَنْ تَرَكَ مَا شُبِّهَ عَلَيْهِ
>   مِنَ الإِثْمِ كَانَ لِمَا اسْتَبَانَ أَتْرَكَ، وَمَنِ اجْتَرَأَ عَلَى
>   مَا يَشُكُّ فِيهِ مِنَ الإِثْمِ أَوْشَكَ أَنْ يُوَاقِعَ مَا
>   اسْتَبَانَ، وَالْمَعَاصِي حِمَى اللَّهِ، مَنْ يَرْتَعْ حَوْلَ الْحِمَى
>   يُوشِكْ أَنْ يُوَاقِعَهُ ‏
>
> Narrated An-Nu`man bin Bashir: The Prophet (ﷺ) said "Both legal and
>   illegal things are obvious, and in between them are (suspicious)
>   doubtful matters. So whoever forsakes those doubtful things lest he
>   may commit a sin, will definitely avoid what is clearly illegal; and
>   whoever indulges in these (suspicious) doubtful things bravely, is
>   likely to commit what is clearly illegal. Sins are Allah's Hima (i.e.
>   private pasture) and whoever pastures (his sheep) near it, is likely
>   to get in it at any moment." (Bukhari)

For extensive discussion on further proofs, see: https://islamqa.info/en/search?q=photography

In addition, I will also say that many girls on facebook and other places are treating the hijab as a fashion statement, and are utilizing different hijab "fashions" in order to draw attention to themselves. This is known to anyone who has the faintest awareness of the different popular social media platforms. **If you abide by the hadith above, this situation would not even arise as with or without hijab, all of it is at the very least makrooh (condemned/disliked).**

Answer (score 0):

This is a very important issue and some Muslim women (Muslimah) do not have awareness about hijab.

In the holy Quran: Surah Ahzab and Surah Noor mentioned about the importance of Hijab for women and it is necessary for every Muslim woman in details.

This is for the security of a women that Non mahrams cannot see her body, because of preventing the spread of Fitna in our society.

In Islamic shariah, the showing of body and adopting the western culture is strictly prohibited.

This is a similar issue that posting photos on social media for girls are not allowed in Islam. The showing of whole body of woman is only for her husband. The fashions and make-up of woman is only for her husband, not for whole society.

Comment: "In islamic shariah, the showing the body and adopting the western culture is strictly prohibited" 
Can you give a reference or have any supporting evidence for this?

Comment: do you think face and hands also never should be shown to strangers? and cannot family members see face of a woman? probably you just forgot these details.